# Boundary condition for finite material

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, boundary-conditions

Consider a solid state material in some domain $[-L,L]^2$ described by a Hamiltonian
$$ \widehat{H} = \frac{\widehat{p}^2}{2m}+V$$

I wonder what kind of boundary condition I have to impose at the boundary for this to describe a realistic piece of matter?

Comment: Why do you take a single-particle Hamiltonian to describe a material?!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases (regardless of periodicity in your lattice), you impose periodic boundary conditions which requires the wavevector to be

$$ k = \frac{2\pi}{L}n, \hspace{0.2cm} n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

in each direction. Note that this doesn't have much physical reasoning other than facilitating computations. In the end, you are interested in the thermodynamic limit, which requires taking volume to infinity from which you recover the continuum limit. Another reason why this doesn't alter physics is that you are not very much interested in the boundary but what happens in the solid itself.

Comment: I think periodic boundary conditions sound very strange to me unless I am interested in a thermodynamic limit which I am explicitly not here, I should say. I don't see any reasons why one end of the material is directly coupled to the other one.

Comment: In the end it doesn't matter very much as L is already the biggest scale in the game and because L is bigger than the length scale of quantum interactions, you will always be in some thermodynamic regime (if you are assuming equilibrium).

Comment: @PritamBemis The answer is correct, with the restriction (as indicated) that you are not interested in "what happens at the surface", i.e. if you are interested in bulk properties only. If this is not the case which you want to study, you should specify this in the question...

Comment: @emirsezik I think it is trivial to adopt the periodic boundary conditions to match the periodicity of the lattice, no?

Comment: @TobiasFünke do you mean when $L = Na$ where $a$ is the lattice spacing ? In that case I agree. Is this still trivial even when $L \neq Na$ for some $N$ ?

Comment: Yes, I mean one should just periodically "repeat" the system along the lattice. IIRC, this is used in e.g. Ashcroft Mermin. Maybe I misinterpreted your sentence in the answer

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!